# Continuously poll as a background service

Tags: rest, loops, grails, quartz-scheduler

So I was reading this topic:
[Continuously poll a REST service in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092814/continuously-poll-a-rest-service-in-grails)

What I'm looking for is slightly different. I want to continually update a list of users so I want to create an endless loop that will run as a background service that continually grabs the next user, makes a REST call, update the user, and then grabs the next one.

I thought about implementing quartz, but because a REST call is being made I don't want to have multiple threads running or set it on some cadence. I'd rather if a single thread continually ran and when the user is updated it continues onto the next user.

If anything, I'd want a quartz job to check to make sure the loop is still properly looping and re-start it if the thread dies for some reason.

Comment: Using busy-wait is highly discouraged. if you don't wish to use quartz , I would recommend using an executor service with a pool of 1+ thread, with scheduled task for every T time, though using wait and notify on change will be much wiser. check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I implemented this with quartz. There is a setting allows me to avoid multiple threads from running simultaneously and I've never run into issues where the thread dies unless an exception isn't handled.

`def concurrent = false`

From the [Quartz Plugin Documentation](http://www.grails.org/plugin/quartz):

> "By default Jobs are executed in concurrent fashion, so new Job execution can start even if previous execution of the same Job is still running. If you want to override this behavior you can use 'concurrent' property, in this case Quartz's StatefulJob will be used"